# how to use REST Service in android ? ( to get data from a PC's database )

Tags: android, rest

I want to get data from a PC's database . I want to use REST Service to do this job . Can any body helps ?? that how to make a REST service on my Computer to get data from database .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following link is to create REST API
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

and how to use it in android

http://www.simpleprogrammer.com/2011/06/04/oauth-and-rest-in-android-part-2/